# How can I name a label node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

I have recently discovered the possibility to adjust the baseline of a `tikzpicture` via the `baseline=...` key. However, this requires the node at which the baseline should be oriented to have a proper name. For some node types, like the ones produced with the `label=...` key, it is not obvious how they can be named.

In the following example, how can the labels reading `A` in the two pictures below be aligned with the baseline of the arrow between them?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[baseline=(Alabel.base)]
\coordinate[draw,shape=circle,label=left:Y](Y);
\coordinate[draw,shape=circle,right=of Y,label=right:A] (A);
\coordinate[draw,shape=circle,above=of Y,label=left:X] (X);
\coordinate[draw,shape=circle,below=of Y,label=left:Z] (Z);
\draw[->,shorten >=5pt,shorten <=5pt] (Y) -- (A);
\draw[->,shorten >=5pt,shorten <=5pt] (X) -- (A);
\draw[->,shorten >=5pt,shorten <=5pt] (Z) -- (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
$\Rightarrow$
\begin{tikzpicture}%[baseline=(Alabel.base)]
\coordinate[draw,shape=circle,label=left:Y](Y);
\coordinate[draw,shape=circle,right=of Y,label=right:A] (A);
\coordinate[draw,shape=circle,above=of Y,label=left:X] (X);
\draw[->,shorten >=5pt,shorten <=5pt] (Y) -- (A);
\draw[->,shorten >=5pt,shorten <=5pt] (X) -- (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Following the PGFmanual, the properties of the label nodes can be set with the syntax

```
label={[key=value]position:text}
```

In the given example, the solution is as follows:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(Alabel.base)]
\coordinate[draw,shape=circle,label=left:Y](Y);
\coordinate[draw,shape=circle,right=of Y,label={[name=Alabel]right:A}] (A);
\coordinate[draw,shape=circle,above=of Y,label=left:X] (X);
\coordinate[draw,shape=circle,below=of Y,label=left:Z] (Z);
\draw[->,shorten >=5pt,shorten <=5pt] (Y) -- (A);
\draw[->,shorten >=5pt,shorten <=5pt] (X) -- (A);
\draw[->,shorten >=5pt,shorten <=5pt] (Z) -- (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
$\Rightarrow$
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(Alabel.base)]
\coordinate[draw,shape=circle,label=left:Y](Y);
\coordinate[draw,shape=circle,right=of Y,label={[name=Alabel]right:A}] (A);
\coordinate[draw,shape=circle,above=of Y,label=left:X] (X);
\draw[->,shorten >=5pt,shorten <=5pt] (Y) -- (A);
\draw[->,shorten >=5pt,shorten <=5pt] (X) -- (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: example alignment]