# Referencing a node's label in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to reference a label of a given node in TikZ. For example, for the node

```
\node[draw, label={above:a label}] (n) {$n$};
```

I want to reuse the label for a like

```
\draw (n.label) -- (1,0);
```

which, of course, does not work. Any idea how I can reference this label (which is another node)?

Comment: A label is a node, so can it be named and reused afterwards. [Follow this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215998/how-can-i-name-a-label-node).

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly I was looking for!